# How to Make Calls using Twilio in Asynchronous mode - Classic ASP?

Tags: twilio

Normally, when I run my Classic ASP script to make calls, for 200 calls, it takes approx 190 seconds to load the page. How can I make asynchronous call to Twilio, so that my page loads quicker rather than waiting for response from Twilio for each call?

I have tried adding CallBackStatus url, however, it didn't help. Here is my code:

```
sub CallANumberSpeakAMessage(fromnumber,tonumber,url)

if isnull(fromnumber) or isnull(tonumber) then exit sub
if len(tonumber) < 10 then exit sub

dim baseurl
dim smsurl
dim from
dim recipient
dim body
dim postdata
dim displayreturn

baseUrl = "https://api.twilio.com"
baseUrl = baseUrl & "/2010-04-01/Accounts/" & authSID & "/Calls"

  'Debug
'response.write "BaseURL:" & baseUrl & "<br><br>"

'setup the request and authorization
Set http = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
http.open "POST", baseUrl, False, authSID, authToken
http.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

mFromPhone = fromnumber ' the number to call from
mToPhone = tonumber ' the number to dial
url = Url ' URL handler for the call, should return TwiML
callBackUrl = "http://www.abcserver.com/status_callback.asp"

postData = "From=" & Server.URLEncode(mFromPhone)
postData = postData & "&To=" & Server.URLEncode(mToPhone)
postData = postData & "&Url=" & Server.URLEncode(url)
postData = postData & "&Method=GET"
postData = postData & "&StatusCallback=" & Server.URLEncode(callBackUrl)
postData = postData & "&IfMachine=Continue"

http.send postData
Set http = Nothing
end sub
```

I have tried changing this "http.open "POST", baseUrl, False, authSID, authToken" to "http.open "POST", baseUrl, True, authSID, authToken". The page loads fast as the ServerXMLHTTP object makes an async call, however, it doesn't really make the call to Twilio, and nothing really happens.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.